# Sync horizontal scroll event of two DataGridViews

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, synchronization

I need to synchronize the scroll event of two `DataGridView` controls, so that when I horizontally scroll the first DGV, second DGV also should be scrolled in the same way.

Is it possible? Could this be set in design time?

Comment: Do you want this to be a two way sync?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This can be done in code as follows. You may be looking for a C# way of doing it. But following is a code I used in a VB.NET application. Just convert it to C# ;)

**For First Grid** write...

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_Scroll(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.ScrollEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.Scroll

        If e.ScrollOrientation = ScrollOrientation.VerticalScroll Then Exit Sub
        If Me.DataGridView2.Rows.Count > 0 And Me.DataGridView1.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            Me.DataGridView2.HorizontalScrollingOffset = e.NewValue 'Me.DataGridView1.HorizontalScrollingOffset
        End If

End Sub
```

**For Second Grid** write...

```
Private Sub DataGridView2_Scroll(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.ScrollEventArgs) Handles DataGridView2.Scroll

        If e.ScrollOrientation = ScrollOrientation.VerticalScroll Then Exit Sub
        If Me.DataGridView1.Rows.Count > 0 And Me.DataGridView2.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            Me.DataGridView1.HorizontalScrollingOffset = e.NewValue 'Me.DataGridView2.HorizontalScrollingOffset
        End If

End Sub
```

Hope this helped?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a C# example; translated from @CAD's answer

If using Visual Studio, you can create a blank function easily by clicking the blank cell next to "Scroll" in listeners.

[image: scroll listener]

Then add the same to both:

```
private void dataGridViewLeft_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ScrollOrientation == ScrollOrientation.HorizontalScroll && dataGridViewLeft.Rows.Count > 0 && dataGridViewRight.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        dataGridViewRight.HorizontalScrollingOffset = dataGridViewLeft.HorizontalScrollingOffset;
    }
}

private void dataGridViewRight_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ScrollOrientation == ScrollOrientation.HorizontalScroll && dataGridViewRight.Rows.Count > 0 && dataGridViewLeft.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        dataGridViewLeft.HorizontalScrollingOffset = dataGridViewRight.HorizontalScrollingOffset;
    }
}
```