# DataGridViews with synchronized scrollbars: Scrollbar position resets on resize

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, scrollbar

I have two `DataGridViews`, one on top of the other, in my form with synchronized scrollbars like in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24466721/sync-horizontal-scroll-event-of-two-datagridviews). However, the synchronization is only one way as I have hidden the scrollbar of the grid on top, only showing one scrollbar for both grids.  The synchronizing works fine while scrolling the scrollbar, but `HorizontalScrollingOffset` of the top grid (the one with the hidden scrollbar that is scrolled programmatically) is reset to 0 when the grid is resized.

I think it's because the scrollbar is hidden for the top grid, so the scrollbar isn't able to hold a scrolling value, but haven't been able to find a solution/workaround yet.
Does anyone know how to prevent the `DataGridView` with the hidden scrollbar from resetting when the `DataGridView` is resized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    private int scrollPosition = 0;

    private void dataGridView_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
    {
        // While scrolling, keep track of the scroll position
        if (e.ScrollOrientation == ScrollOrientation.HorizontalScroll)
        {
            this.scrollPosition = e.NewValue;
        }
    }

    private void dataGridView_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Re-scroll back to where we were
        dataGridView.HorizontalScrollingOffset = this.scrollPosition;
    }
```

Comment: This did the trick.  I originally thought of this solution but then disregarded it because I thought it would make the grid jump back and forth while resizing.  However, it turns out it works smoothly and there doesn't seem to be any issues.  Thanks!